# What the "reject" method in the ruby optionparser does?

Tags: ruby, optparse

There is an "accept" example in the documentation. But i can't figure out what is the use of the "reject" method? Can somebody explain the sense and give some usage example?

I tried to read the source but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It simply undoes `accept`.

For example, using the [snippet](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Creating+Custom+Conversions) in documentation demonstrating `accept`:

```
op.accept(User) do |user_id|
  find_user user_id.to_i
end
```

If after that we issue `op.reject(User)`, `User` will no longer be accepted — as if `op.accept(User) ...` was never specified. If we try, the code would generate `unsupported argument type: User (ArgumentError)`.

Comment: I can't imagine a real life example where this could be usefull. Do you?

Comment: No, but it doesn't mean one doesn't exist. It's probably a "just in case" thing - indeed, I think anytihng doable should be undoable, just in case. My complaint is mainly that it is not documented properly, not that I can't imagine using it.